# Concatenating one data frame with a list using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file like

```
F1,F2,F3
A1,2,4,2
A2,4,1,2
```

which I use this code to get the first row and first column labels.

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", index_col=[0])
features = df.columns
targets = df.index

Index(['F1', 'F2', 'F3'], dtype='object')
Index(['A1', 'A2'], dtype='object')
```

After some manipulation, I create another array which looks like

```
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents, columns = ['pc1', 'pc2'])

        pc1       pc2
0 -1.292928  0.663255
1 -0.297064 -0.293463
```

Now, I want to concatenate the `targets` to `principalDf` to have

```
        pc1       pc2   KK
0 -1.292928  0.663255   A1
1 -0.297064 -0.293463   A2
```

I put `KK` as a dummy label for better representation. I mean appending an array with the same number of rows to the left  matrix.

It seems that `finalDf = pd.concat([principalDf, targets], axis = 1)` is not correct because I get this error

```
cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

I don't know if there is a problem with the syntax or it is due to the missing `KK` in the target list. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can concat only `pandas objects` with `pd.concat`**, so convert your `list` to `df` and then concat:

```
In [2373]: pd.concat([principalDf, pd.DataFrame(targets, columns=['KK'])], 1)
Out[2373]: 
        pc1       pc2  KK
0 -1.292928  0.663255  A1
1 -0.297064 -0.293463  A2
```

Comment: I wouldnt say only... but nice answer..!

Comment: @adirabargil Is it fine now? I've updated.

Comment: But cant you concat with append for example?